# Things to look at before buying1988 xj40 jaguar

Tags: old-cars, buying, jaguar

Would you recommend me buying 1988 xj40 jaguar? overall the car works, and I have given it  a test drive, but it seemed heavy and the steering was a little bit hard.
The engine ran good I guess, and the transmission was not that smooth but I don't really know...

I am not sure what are the major things to look for in this car, can anyone help?

Thanks [This is a link to the online seller.](https://jo.opensooq.com/en/search/69340992/used-jaguar-1988)

Comment: It seemed heavy - cars built back then had less plastic c**p, steering hard - again car designers have bent to the will of the feeble population and made the controls so light a 10 year old can drive a car - physically anyway (not suggesting they should, but I learnt at 10 with a vehicle that did not have power steering, power brakes etc etc and if some people were given that to drive they would not be able to...

Comment: Best place for info is one of the jaguar forums - and they have facs about buying etc...

Comment: try here : http://www.jaguarforum.com/forumdisplay.php?f=96

Answer (score 2):

An XJ40 weighs nearly 2 tons, so no wonder it feels heavy. It has power-assisted everything so the steering shouldn't feel heavy, so you might have a leak in the power steering circuit.
If it has the early digital dashboard (with a screen that shows all the warnings as large icons), that dashboard is prone to problems, so check if that works well.